# How to change header color of ion-menu, without changing color of ion-navbar?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-menu, ion-navbar

I have this below code for ion navbar, where I am having one menu icon on the right side. And I  want to change the color of that menu header.But when i am changing color of ion-navbar , it is changing for menu header also.I want separate color for both ion-navbar and ion-menu.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" id="menu2">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar class="menu_header">
            <ion-title>MyApp</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list no-lines>
             <button ion-item  menuClose="menu2" detail-none>
              Item1
            </button>
            <button ion-item  menuClose="menu2" detail-none>
                Item2
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar primary>
        <ion-title class="header-title" text-center>
            Home
        </ion-title>
        <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle="right" end >
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

And for changing the color of ion-navbar I am adding the below line in variable.scss

```
$toolbar-background: #EF473A;
```

Can anyone please help me how to keep the separate color for both?

Comment: can u provide a demo

Comment: If you will create a project using "ionic start myApp sidemenu ".After the project create, I want to keep separate color for "Home" page header. And separate color for "side menu" header.
github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-sidemenu This project only i am having. @Sa E Chowdary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color only for the titles, you could use the classes

```
.header-title {
  color: blue;
}
.menu_header {
  color: #EF473A;
}
```

If you'd like to change the color for the whole header You can either do it on the element:

```
body > ion-header {
  color: blue;
}
ion-menu > ion-header {
  color: #EF473A;
}
```

or alternatively add a class to the elements you want to modify, but that potentially mean editing a third party component...

Comment: @ananya do you have an example of your CSS and maybe a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve? I guess I don't understand your question correctly...

Comment: If you will create a project using "ionic start myApp sidemenu ".After the project create, I want to keep separate color for "Home" page header. And separate color for "side menu" header. @Michaël Vanderheyden

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-sidemenu
This project only i am having. @Michaël Vanderheyden

Comment: @ananya, I updated the solution above based on the repo you shared

Comment: I got the solution.
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  customColor:(
    base: #0f456f,
    contrast: #ffffff
  )
);
And i am adding customColor in ion-navbar